# Groovy @Grab NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ivy/plugins/resolver/DependencyResolver

Tags: groovy

Using @grab for the first time (new to groovy)

I understand it is meant to work "out the box."

However, when I add this to my class:

`@Grab(group='commons-lang', module='commons-lang', version='2.4')`

I get the following compilation error:

`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ivy/plugins/resolver/DependencyResolver`

Groovy version is `Groovy Version: 3.0.4 JVM: 11.0.1 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X`

Comment: how do you start groovy?

Comment: through an intellij unittest.
But compiling through gradle throws a compilation error too, also referring to DepenencyResolveer

Comment: then you have missing dependency to ivy-2.4.0.jar

Comment: you could setup dependency to [groovy-all](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/3.0.4). it includes all other libraries

Comment: solved it! the weird thing is I had tried putting ivy in the build.gradle both as buildSrc and regular dependencies

Comment: Please make your two comments into an answer. This problem is mentioned all over the internet but no definitive answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have missing dependency or library `ivy-2.4.0.jar`

this library is a part of [groovy-all](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/3.0.4) artifact. check [groovy-all.pom](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/3.0.4/groovy-all-3.0.4.pom) to see all groovy dependencies/features

so, you could setup dependency to `groovy-all` artifact in your project

or to a separate  [ivy-2.4.0.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ivy/ivy/2.4.0) artifact if you don't want to include all groovy features into your project

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to `gradle.build`

```
configurations {
  ivy
}

dependencies {
  ivy "org.apache.ivy:ivy:2.4.0"
 ...
}

tasks.withType(GroovyCompile) {
  groovyClasspath += configurations.ivy
}
```