# How to retrieve oauth2.0 access token for grant type Client Credentials in Groovy

Tags: groovy, oauth-2.0, access-token, ready-api

I am using **ReadyAPI (SoapUI - pro)** and able to manually retrieve the OAuth2.0 **Access Token** for grant type Client Credentials.

[image: 1]

How can I make this **Access Token** retrieval automated in Groovy script so that I could run it from command line without GUI interaction. The Groovy code I am using is:

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7.1')

import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import groovyx.net.http.Method
import groovyx.net.http.ContentType

def clientId = '*************-ac6efba39e6a'
def clientSecret = '**********_icH6Nr6.7'
def tokenUrl = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/*******/oauth2/v2.0/token'

// First, we obtain an access token using the client credentials grant
def http = new HTTPBuilder(tokenUrl)
http.request(Method.POST, ContentType.URLENC) { req ->
    body = [
        grant_type: 'client_credentials',
        client_id: clientId,
        client_secret: clientSecret
    ]
    response.success = { resp, reader ->
        // Extract the access token from the response
        def accessToken = resp.data.access_token
        // Now we can use the access token to make API requests
        makeApiRequest(accessToken)
    }
}

// Finally, we can use the access token to make API requests
def makeApiRequest(accessToken) {
    def http = new HTTPBuilder('https://***-npd.az****.ca')
    http.request(Method.GET, ContentType.JSON) { req ->
        headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer $accessToken"
        response.success = { resp, reader ->
            // Handle the API response
            println resp.data
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ivy/util/MessageLogger
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing .jar in your Groovy setup.

Check the answers in this thread. They might help.

[Groovy @Grab NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ivy/plugins/resolver/DependencyResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62439105/groovy-grab-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-ivy-plugins-resolver-dependencyres)